# UIStackView does not resize after unhiding

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Am new to stack views but am trying to hide and unhide a block of nested subviews from a button in a parallel stack view. Hiding works (the targeted stack view shrinks down to one line and goes away) but when I try to unhide, the nested stack view (actually a stack of rows, each one a stack of columns) does not expand back out again. I just get one line. Code is below

```
import UIKit

class Grid: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mainGrid: UIStackView!

    @IBAction func examplesPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 10.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in
            self.mainGrid.hidden =  !self.mainGrid.hidden
            }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

with an image before the hide operation (pressing example)

[image: before hiding]

and what I get when I try to unhide

[image: after attempted unhide]

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Did you try without the animation block ?

Comment: good idea; just tired it but no, does not help

Comment: How are you creating the stackviews in the first place?  I would like to see that code or the storyboard where you laid them out.

Comment: Experienced the same thing. In my case it was enough to set the alignment Top instead of default Fill.

Comment: Many thanks for that. For me it seemed to help hidding all child stack views first.